# Laravel. Full Text search returns 0 rows

Tags: laravel, full-text-search

I am a little new to Laravel and loving the framework but I am trying to get a FULL TEXT search working with no luck! I will let the code do the explaining...

**My controller**

```
public function search() {
    $table = Table::searchFilter('Name');
    return $tables;
}
```

**My Model**

```
public static function searchFilter($data, $pageLimit = '5') {

    $keyword = !is_array($data) ? array('+'.$data.'*') : $data;
    $matchArray = array('name', 'country', 'Region');
    $columns = array();
    foreach($matchArray as $column)
    {
        $columns[] = $column;
    }
    $match = implode(',', $columns);
    $result =  self::whereRaw('MATCH('.$match.') AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', $keyword)
                ->paginate($pageLimit);

    return $result;
}
```

**Return**

```
{"total":0,"per_page":5,"current_page":1,"last_page":0,"from":0,"to":0,"data":[]}
```

**Entries**

Thanks so much for all of your help!

Comment: Can you provide the SQL query that works without using Eloquent?

Comment: If you can't run the SQL directly against the server, this has nothing to do with Laravel.

Comment: Many thanks Nathan, you have pointed me in the right direction. I will post my fix once I have found the missconfiguration.